# How to iteratively optimize a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, caching, query-optimization

I'm trying to iteratively optimize a slow MySQL query, which means I run the query, get timing, tweak it, re-run it, get timing, etc.  The problem is that the timing is non-stationary, and later executions of the query perform very differently from earlier executions.

I know to clear the query cache, or turn it off, between executions.  I also know that, at some level, the OS will affect query performance in ways MySQL can't control or understand.  But in general, what's the best I can do wrt this kind of iterative query optimization, so that I can compare apples to apples?

Comment: did you try `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...`? That's usually enough to make the query run times stable over many runs.

Comment: I haven't, and I will, and then I'll report back.  Thank you.

Comment: Okay, tried it -- no effect.  Once the performance boost kicks in after the initial query, the query is way faster.  But thanks for the tip, this will be useful to know in other contexts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *best* tool for query optimization is [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html).  It will take a bit to [learn what the output means](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html), but after doing so, you will understand how MySQL's (horrible, broken, backwards) query planner decides to best retrieve the requested data.

Changes in the parameters to the query can result in wildly different query plans, so this may account for some of the problems you are seeing.

You might want to consider [using the slow query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/slow-query-log.html) to capture *all* queries that might be running with low performance.  Perhaps you'll find that the query in question only falls into the low performance category when it uses certain parameters?

Comment: Thanks for the tip regarding EXPLAIN -- that will be a big help.  I am already scrutinizing the slow query log, and I think maybe this will ultimately be what I need to press harder on: build up a corpus of queries that are slow, then run them in a batch, hoping that the ones that find their way into the slow query log are sufficiently different to produce performance robust to the caching effects I described in my comment to squawknull (below.)

Comment: @shanusmagnus, if this is ends up being merely a case of disk block caching (or lack thereof), you should examine the MySQL configuration to determine if it's already been tuned for performance on that hardware, for the given database size.  Percona's [MySQL Performance Blog](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/) may be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

Create a script that runs the query 1000 times, or whatever number of iterations causes the results to stabilize.

Then follow your process as described above, but just make sure you aren't relying on a single execution, but rather an average of multiple executions, because you're right, the results will not be stable as row counts change, and your machine is doing other things.

Also, try to use a wide array of inputs to the query, if that makes sense for your use case.

Comment: This is good advice generally, but sadly not that helpful in my particular case, where a single query takes the execution time from 25 seconds to 700 ms on subsequent queries.  Clearly caching is at work, and it seems to be OS-level caching on the relevant disk blocks.  Queries of the same kind that are 'sufficiently different' can knock the execution time back up to the 25 second range, but it's non-trivial automatically creating queries that are sufficiently different to exercise the system in this manner.